# How to add prefix to Axis label in core plot

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios7, core-plot

I'm using core plot in my project.I have a requirement to add "$" as prefix in Y axis label using `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic`.Please guide me how to do this?
One more issue with labelling policy.
if i use `CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic` then i'm getting UI like image [image]
 As you can see the y label are on graph.Anything i'm missing?
In the above image i need to alternate x axis lines.How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure the `labelFormatter` on the y-axis to add the currency symbol. [`NSNumberFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) gives you many options.

You need to add padding on the plot area frame to leave room for the labels, e.g., `graph.plotAreaFrame.paddingLeft = 50.0;`.

Comment: Thank you Eric,One more thing in the question is i want the x axis lines to be alternate ,how can i do this?

Comment: Use one line style for the major grid lines and another for the minor grid lines. Adjust the labeling policy and related parameters as needed to keep the spacing where you want it. You can set a formatter and text style for the minor ticks, too. Use the same ones that you use on the major ticks to get labels that look the same.